# Users, Groups and Tags database design

Tags: sql, database-design

Im having difficulty trying to design a database structure for the following scenario:

> My database should contain general user information UserID, FirstName,
>   LastName, JoiningDate.
>
> Each User can be part of a group.
>
> Each group has "tags" attached to it and can have multiple tags.  Users
>   should also be able to return a list of available groups (filtered by
>   tags).
>
> Be able to search for a group (by tags attached to the group), and
>   searching for particular users (by last name, or unique ID). ).   It should also be able 
>   to return a list of available groups (filtered by tags), and the
>   members of a particular group (filtered by last name and filtered by
>   joining date).
>
> There should also be a means of discovering which
>   groups of users belong to a number of groups (a query on
>   “who are the members of "Bravo group" and the "Delta" 
>   group), and keeping track of messages sent in the group (like a
>   forum).

Is this just two tables? Or should it be three tables... Users, Groups and Tags? Its been almost a year since ive did any relational database stuff and I was wondering if anyone could show a visual representation of this database design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest five tables: Users, Groups, Tags and link tables UserGroups and GroupTags.

This is because there appears to be a many-to-many relationship between Users and Groups, and between Groups and Tags - a link entity is required in relational design to join entities with many-to-many relationships between them.

```
 ---------   ------------   --------
 | Users |   |  Groups  |   | Tags |
 ---------   ------------   --------
     |         |      |        |
     |         |      |        |
    /|\       /|\    /|\      /|\
   --------------    -------------
   | UserGroups |    | GroupTags |
   --------------    -------------
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, is it possible you could show this in a diagram?

Comment: ha I like how you took the time to do that I was just meaning a quick screen dump but yeah it helps!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Definitely at least 3: User, Groups and Tags.

And because you are using a many to many relationship (assumption from your description) between groups and tags you'd probably need a cross table to link groups and tags together.

If one user can belong to more groups, there should also be cross table between users and groups.