# Database Design for user defined groups

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design a database to support private user-defined groups. Pretty much identical to how Google Circles are. These are to be for **JUST** the user, much like circles are - that's why creating a user group design like I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805712/2580503 would be undesirable.

So far the only solution I can come up with is to have a table like this:

> > USER_ID | GROUP_ID | ARRAY(USER_ID)

Where the PKEY would actually be a compound key of (USER_ID, GROUP_ID). This way a user could have multiple groups.

Would greatly appreciate any feedback on this proposed solution and would love to hear if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just to clarify, GROUP_ID would not reference a separate table, it would just indicate the number group for that user. Also there would be a name etc. for the group as well - just wasn't necessary to include as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must involve at least three (3) tables if you want a normalized design. USERS, USER_GROUPS, and USER_GROUPS_MEMBERS. You are correct that the PK of USER_GROUPS would be a dyad (USER, GROUP). The PK of USER_GROUPS_MEMBERS would be a triad (USER, GROUP, USER).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
Groups (GROUP_ID, USER_ID, GROUP_NAME)
Members (MEMBER_ID, GROUP_ID, USER_ID)
```

Although `Groups` might appear backwards, it actually lists the `USER_ID` that owns a `GROUP_ID` while `Members` gives the `MEMBER_ID` to which could be associated rows that have to do with this `USER_ID` in the given `GROUP_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
**Users**
id, name

**Groups**
id, name

**User_Groups**
id, user_id, group_id

**Group_users**
id, user_group_id, user_id
```

I have separated `groups` and `user_groups` assuming that there could be possibilities that you wish to have a few default `groups` for every user, If this is not the case, you can move the `group_name` directly to the `user_groups` and ignore the `groups` table